# Rsyslog SSL/TLS connection issue with authmode x509/name

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, rsyslog

Unable to connect rsyslog server through java client for SSL connections with auth mode x509/name.

Logged in to VM and generated certificates using the below commands

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem
# Create CA certificate
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 3600 -key ca-key.pem -out ca.pem -subj "/CN=selfsigned-ca-certificate"
# Create server certificate
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem -subj "/CN=selfsigned-server-certificate"
openssl rsa -in server-key.pem -out server-key.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 3600 -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out server-cert.pem
# Verify certificates and you should see in response as "server-cert.pem: OK"
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem server-cert.pem
```

**/etc/rsyslog.conf**

```
module(load="imtcp" StreamDriver.AuthMode="x509/name" StreamDriver.Mode="1")
module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
module(load="imklog") # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)

$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /root/certs/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /root/certs/server-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /root/certs/server-key.pem

$InputTCPServerRun 6514

$template applogs,"/var/log/applogs.log"

*.* ?applogs
```

java client to connect syslog server

```
public static void getSyslogConfig(SyslogConfig syslogConfig, TcpSyslogMessageSender messageSender)
            throws CertificateException,
            KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        messageSender.setDefaultAppName("MyApp");
        messageSender.setDefaultFacility(Facility.USER);
        messageSender.setDefaultSeverity(Severity.INFORMATIONAL);
        messageSender.setSyslogServerHostname(syslogConfig.getSyslogServerIP()); // syslog server ip
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate) certFactory
                .generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                        Base64.decodeBase64(syslogConfig.getCertificateData().getBytes())));
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keystore.load(null);
        keystore.setCertificateEntry("cert-alias", caCert); // caCert contains server-cert.pem
        messageSender.setSyslogServerPort(Integer.valueOf(syslogConfig.getSyslogServerPort()));
        messageSender.setMessageFormat(MessageFormat.RFC_5425);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                .loadTrustMaterial(keystore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .build();
        messageSender.setSSLContext(sslContext);
        messageSender.setSsl(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   TcpSyslogMessageSender messageSender = new TcpSyslogMessageSender()
   getSyslogConfig(syslogConfig, messageSender);
   messageSender.sendMessage("Hello World");
}
```

Error seen on the syslog server are

```
023-08-01T11:07:01.181383+00:00 ip-10-0-143-30 rsyslogd: peer did not provide a certificate, not permitted to talk to it [v8.2001.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2085 ]
```

Had setup syslog client on another VM with configuration

/etc/rsyslog.conf on client machine

```
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /root/certs/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /root/certs/client-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /root/certs/client-key.pem

#$InputTCPServerRun 6514

$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # require TLS for the connection
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer *

# set up the action for all messages
action(
type="omfwd"
target="*"
protocol="tcp"
port="6514"
StreamDriver="ossl"
StreamDriverMode="1" # run driver in TLS-only mode
StreamDriverAuthmode="anon"
)

$template applogs,"/var/log/applogs.log"

*.* ?applogs
```

error for client machine is

```
2023-08-01T12:25:15.084163+00:00 ip-10-0-143-30 rsyslogd: gnutls returned error on handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received.  [v8.2001.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2083 ]
2023-08-01T12:26:00.946226+00:00 ip-10-0-143-30 rsyslogd: unexpected GnuTLS error -15 in nsdsel_gtls.c:178: An unexpected TLS packet was received.  [v8.2001.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2078 ]
```

Comment: You seem to only load the trust store in Java. If you want to authenticate to the server you need to configure client auth as well.